# I have the following YAML file whose errors I want to ignore

Tags: kubernetes

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  name: mysqldb-1
  labels:
   app.kubernetes.io: mysqldb-1
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 100Mi
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  name: mysqldb-2
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io: mysqldb-2
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 100Mi

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mysqldb-service
  labels:
   app.kubernetes.io: mysqldb
spec:
  ports:
    - name: "5306"
      port: 5306
      targetPort: 3306
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io: mysqldb
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mysqldb
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io: mysqldb
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io: mysqldb
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io: mysqldb
  spec:
      containers:
          -name: mysqldb
          image: mysql:8.0
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3306
      volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /var/lib/mysql
              name: mysqldb-1
            - mountPath: /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
              name: mysqldb-2
      restartPolicy: Always
      volumes:
        - name: mysqldb-1
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: mysqldb-1
        - name: mysqldb-2
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: mysqldb-2
status: {}
```

I got this error

```
Error from server (BadRequest): error when creating "mysqldb.yaml": Deployment in version "v1" cannot be handled as a Deployment: strict decoding error: unknown field "spec.spec"
```

How do I go about ignoring the errors for an included yaml file?

Comment: Please take a moment to edit your question and properly format the YAML manifests. There is help available in the editor.

Answer (score 0):

There are indentation issues in your `Deployment` resource. Also, add resource limits for the containers.

Try this one:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mysqldb
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io: mysqldb
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io: mysqldb
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io: mysqldb
    spec:
        containers:
          - name: mysqldb
            image: mysql:8.0
            ports:
              - containerPort: 3306
            resources:
              requests:
                memory: "256Mi"
                cpu: "500m"
              limits:
                memory: "512Mi"
                cpu: "1000m"
        volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /var/lib/mysql
              name: mysqldb-1
            - mountPath: /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
              name: mysqldb-2
        restartPolicy: Always
        volumes:
          - name: mysqldb-1
            persistentVolumeClaim:
              claimName: mysqldb-1
          - name: mysqldb-2
            persistentVolumeClaim:
              claimName: mysqldb-2
status: {}
```

NOTE: You can use an IDE extension for Kubernetes to get errors and warnings for YAML resource issues easily.